# Auto disable ReSharper based on the project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Is there any way to disable/enable ReSharper based on the project name or solution file in Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you mean Resharper?

Comment: Which parts of R# do you want to disable? The inspections?

Comment: The whole Reshaper (same as Visual Studio->Tools->Options->Suspend Now) ...  Here is what we have to do now. When we open a old legacy project, we have to go to suspend the Resharper manually by pressing a VS shortcut or from Tools\Options\Resharper. Otherwise, the VS will be crashed. but When we are on new project, we have to resume the Resharper.